# Why does this c++ structure get padded?

Tags: c++, memory, structure, padding, memory-alignment

I have two data structures that I am passing through this function to check they are (likely) padded or not.

```
  template<typename T>
  constexpr bool has_padding() noexcept
  {
    return !std::is_standard_layout<T>() || alignof(T) != 1;
  }
```

This data structure passes with no issues:

```
  struct txin_to_key
  {
    uint64_t amount;
    std::vector<uint64_t> key_offsets;
    crypto::key_image k_image;      // double spending protection
  };
```

but this structure fails:

```
struct txin_to_key_public
{
  crypto::hash tx_hash;
  uint64_t amount;
  uint32_t relative_offset;
};
```

Key_image and hash are both char[32] under the hood. When I wrap the second structure in a pragma pack (1) I'm fine though. What is the issue with the vanilla version of the second structure?

Comment: what is `crypto::hash`?  This is like asking why a car is making a funny noise and not saying what kind of car it is.  We could do a lucky guess... Provide a [mcve], which could involve writing your own crypto hash that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Why does it matter?  This sure seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you have somehow decided that structure padding is your problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I don't quite understand your test, but the second struct likely needs 4 bytes of padding at the end, since its size must be a multiple of the 8 bytes of alignment that `uint64_t` probably needs.  It's all implementation and ABI dependent, of course.

Comment: @yak I already said in the post what it is (char [32]). I get the same issues regardless of the order of the variables in the struct. It matters because my library (first function) and operations on what it produces don't work otherwise

Comment: @TrancendentalObject Not sure what meaning you ascribe to `has_padding`. Under many implementations `has_padding<int>()` will return `true` for example.

Comment: @tranc then replace it with a `char[32]`, confirm it still has the problem.  Or not.  Don't just claim it, do it, and provide a [mcve] to make it easy for others to verify.

Comment: what are you talking about? It is a char[32] by typedef. I have provided a MRE.

Comment: @TrancendentalObject `I have provided a MRE` No you haven't: https://godbolt.org/z/vG63xr

Comment: The function `has_padding` does not make much sense as written.  `has_unique_object_representations` seems to be closer to what you might need (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations).

Comment: Very poor question. Unknown type. Unknown library function. No explanation of **Does not works** etc. The help you will likely get is proportinal to the quality and effort put in a question.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the issue with the vanilla version of the second structure?

There is no "issue".

If you mean, why is `has_padding<txin_to_key_public>` true, that is because the alignment requirement of `uint32_t` and/or `uint64_t` is greater than 1 on your system.

> so why then does the first txin_to_key ... [has_padding returns true]

Because `std::vector<uint64_t>` is not a standard layout class. Probably would also be because of the alignments just like in the second case.

You can verify which conditions of `condition1 || condition2` are true by inspecting them separately.

Comment: so why then does the first txin_to_key work given that it has a char[32] inside also?

Comment: @TrancendentalObject Describe "does work". I don't understand your question.

Comment: has_padding returns true for txin_to_key_public